# Running docker in subprocess on Python PyCharm

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I have a command that looks like:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['docker', 'run', 'imagename'])
```

in a Python program. I am able to execute this successfully from terminal, however when I run it in PyCharm I receive this error:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host

How can I fix this error to run in the Python IDE?

Answer (score 0):

The key is in understanding what `eval "$(docker-machine env dockermachinename)"` returns (where dockermachinename is your docker machine name(you can check the name with "docker-machine ls" command)).

When you run `docker-machine env dockermachinename`  which is what you need to configure your shell to connect with Docker, it prints:

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://999.999.99.999:999"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/enderland/.docker/machine/machines/dockermachinename"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="dockermachinename"
# Run this command to configure your shell: 
# eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

These environment variables need to be within PyCharm. By adding them into your configuration environment variables list, you will be able to connect with Docker.

This assumes your Docker machine is running (if not, you need to do `docker-machine start dockermachinename`).